# meaning of "greasy": greasy floor

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

If the floor is **greasy**, is it necessarily due to grease or oil? Could it be due to detergent or water, for example?

Comment: There's a difference between "being greasy" and "appearing greasy". "the floor is greasy" by itself can't tell you that. Maybe not water though, since most people can easily tell that.

Comment: Have you checked all prestigious dictionaries' definitions?

Answer (score 1):

Water is wet. It may make the floor slippery, but it's not greasy.

Comment: Have you checked all prestigious dictionaries' definitions?

Comment: No, I haven't. Have you? What did you find?

Comment: One definition given by Lexico simply says, "slippery." Another, taken from Macmillan Dictionary, says "covered in a substance such as OIL OR WATER that makes you slip."

Comment: Usually, greasy implies slippery, but it's not a synonym. If Macmillan defines *greasy* as including *covered in water*, then I disagree. The most slippery surfaces are those that are greasy and then have a film of water added, but that's another matter.

Comment: Merriam-Webster also lists "slippery" in one of the definitions. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/greasy

Comment: Yet, it's not what I would call a synonym. Usually, greasy things are slippery, but slippery doesn't imply greasy. In any case, if you want to use *greasy* to mean that something is covered in water, no one can stop you, but I would call it sub-optimal usage.

Comment: Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary lists it as a chiefly British usage.

Answer (score 0):

From [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/greasy)

> resembling grease

> unctuous or oily in manner

You can think of any substance that's oily, but in the case of water I would say it's more likely to be a contamined/dirty water.

Comment: What's your native language?

Comment: Portuguese (Br)